# Undefined array in class?

Tags: javascript

```
function test()
{
    this.lol = [];
}

test.hello = function ()
{
    this.lol.push("hello world");
}

test.hello();

console.log(test.lol);
```

Just a test class, gives me the following:

```
^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When, do you think, is your `test()` called (the one that creates empty array in `lol` field)?

Comment: "What is `this`" is one of the most tricky questions in the js world. Have a look at `this` :) http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you waant to do this you have to do it like:

```
function Test() {
    this.lol = [];
}

Test.prototype.hello = function () {
    this.lol.push("hello world");
}
var test = new Test();
test.hello();
console.log(test.lol);
```

the point is when you use `this` keyboard, you should use it as a `Class` or you should provide the `this` for the context using `call` or `apply`, like:

```
function testFunc() {
    this.lol = [];
}

testFunc.hello = function () {
    this.lol.push("hello world");
}

var test = {};

//this way you call the testFunc with test as its `this`
testFunc.call(test);

//this calls the testFunc.hello with the same `this`
testFunc.hello.call(test);

console.log(test.lol);
```